# Replacing dumb wall switch with smart one (wiring)

Tags: wiring, electrical

Based on the first diagram below (which is the current wiring for my wall switch), is the way I have the second diagram set up correct? My biggest point of confusion is the line/load wires. Judging by the fact that there are two loads (presumably TR and BR), I am assuming that TL is the line. Would this be the correct way to install my new switch?

I am assuming based on the current wiring that the exposed copper wires are ground (green in the diagram), the white wires are neutral (yellow), and the black wires are line/load (red).

Does this work? Is it safe? Should I abort? :P

[image]

Comment: This likely belongs on the DIY SE. Why are you connecting the neutral to the new switch?

Comment: I've flagged the question for migration to DIY.

Comment: Sorry, thought this was the right place. @Samuel The new switch has a neutral wire, so it should be connected to the other neutral wires, no?

Comment: @oldwren I just don't see the point when all three are shorted together. You should probably let us know what switch you're installing.

Comment: @Samuel It's a Wink Tapt switch, similar to the Leviton Z-Wave switch. It has four wires in the back: Line, load, ground, and neutral.

Comment: @oldwren Ah, well it occurs to me that the switch is possibly sipping some power for itself, so needs its own neutral return path. Just connect it like you've drawn.

Comment: Where did the labels (TL, TR, BR) come from, and do they mean something? Without knowing where the wires go (and which is incoming power) it's impossible to answer. If there are two lights and BR and TR both go to each light, then yes, your drawing is correct. If TL is the light, BR is a receptacle (constant power) and BR is the incoming power, then your switch is backwards (and same goes if BR is a receptacle and TR is incoming power).

Comment: To figure out which one is hot, turn off the power, disconnect all the blacks, then cap them individually with wire nuts (for safety). Turn on the power, then use a non-contact voltage detector to figure out which one is live -- and that is the one you connect 'line' on your switch to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you've provided; and without knowing what `TL`, `TR`, and `BR` stand for, I'd say your proposed wiring looks correct. However, this is assuming that `TL` is the feed, and that `TR` and `BR` are devices you want to turn on/off.

Comment: Sorry, TL = top left, TR = top right, BR = bottom right. Just the location in the box for my reference. Based on the fact that both TR and BR seem to be connected with the black wire, it appears to me that they are the devices and that TL is the power. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When revising AC house wiring, never "assume" anything.  Other then the old cliche, making the wrong assumption on house wiring could seriously harm yourself, others, and your house.

First - Read the full instructions/user guide for the product, (hopefully you have, though you haven't indicated this). If needed here it is from the [wink web site (PDF)](http://www.wink.com/downloads/help/quirkyge-tapt-light-switch/user-guide.pdf).

Second - If you are at all in doubt, or feel you are not qualified for modifying house wiring, contact a professional electrician. If there is still some doubt, contact the manufacturer directly, here: 1-844-WINKAPP  - or their [web site](http://www.wink.com/help/products/quirkyge-tapt-light-switch/#contact)